# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state') at FundValueCard.componentWillMount

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router

I want to add one class component inside a functional component which is giving error for componentWillMount

FundValueCard: - (class component)

```js
class FundValueCard extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = {
                data: {},
                translate: 0,
                disableRightArrow: false
            }
        }
    
    componentWillMount() {
    const service = new MyRequestsService();
    service.getListFundDetail(
       this.props.location.state.mySelectedPolicy.policyNumber
    )
      .then(res => res)
      .then((result) => {
        this.setState({
          data: result.data.data,
      });
    }
}
```

Accordion.js-- (functional component)

```js
 return (<Accordion> <FundValueCard /> </Accordion>)
```

Comment: From what I can see in your code, your are not passing any props into your `FundValueCard` but trying to read them inside it. Could you, please, tell is there a value when you try to read this `this.props.location.state.mySelectedPolicy.policyNumber`? Because in your code there is no problem with state inside the `componentWillMount` since your are not even using state here beside setting a new one.

Comment: @DavydVeremchuk ,you are correct i am getting the error for this one "this.props.location.state.mySelectedPolicy.policyNumber".

Comment: "this.props.location.state.mySelectedPolicy.policyNumber" it is getting as "false"

Comment: What "prop" should I add here in <FundValueCard /> so that I can get the value ?
I have tried with <FundValueCard {...this.props} /> , but it is giving error.

Comment: Seems like you don't really understand what your code does since you don't even know what props you should pass. I guess you should pass a `location` prop like that `location={{}}` which should have the following structure inside it `location={state: {mySelectedPolicy: {policyNumber: value,},},}`

Comment: yes value is present inside "this.props.location.state.mySelectedPolicy.policyNumber"